# Does anyone know how to add this in twig template, or in .theme?

Tags: theming, 8

I want this to be converted as a twig functions where can I pass a node id to the functions and display the node information such as link, content body, and image itself.

```
$nid = 1;
$node = node_load($nid);
$output = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_foo');

// $output is a render array, so it needs to be rendered first
print render($output);
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) There's no code writing/conversion service here but we'd be happy to help you with problems in your own code - what did you try, where did you get stuck? Please edit the question and be as detailed as possible

Comment: I tried anything what I see on the web, apply them and get nothing or I just don't get it because I am newbie in Drupal 8 but since I was amazed how interact to the system.

I stuck at displaying the content information of the such as content type like basic page, add a field and type of the field is content where I already create some sort of information retrieve it using the node id.

Thanks for the help guys!
Joe, Newbie in Drupal

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) to render nodes/entities, and views.

> Twig Tweak module provides a Twig extension with some useful functions
>   and filters that can improve development experience.
>
> ```
> {# You can load an entity from the current route. #}
>   <dt>Entity from route:</dt>
>   <dd>{{ drupal_entity('node', null, 'teaser') }}<dd>
>
> {# You can pass arguments to the view if needed. #}
>   <dt>View:</dt>
>   <dd>{{ drupal_view('view_name', 'page_1') }}<dd>
> ```

Comment: Had some errors Unknown "drupal_entity" function or Unknown "drupal_view" function

Comment: @mrjhon01 did you enable the module?

Comment: Yes! I already enable the module, clear some cache and still having the error

Comment: @mrjhon01 on which template are you placing them?

Comment: in the field.html.twig template

Comment: @mrjhon01 after testing myself, it works fine for me in field.html.twig, make sure you add the <dd> tags like this: <dd>{{ drupal_view('view_name', 'page_1') }}</dd>

Comment: I don't what the error all of this, I enable the module and put it in the field.html.twig and still got an error Unknown drupal_entity functions.

By the way thanks for your help... though I still get error in the code

Comment: @mrjhon01 hmmm, which version of D8 are you using?

Comment: I think it's beta, hmmm i forgot which version of D8 I am currently using

Comment: @mrjhon01 if it's beta, thats probably the problem, you should upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: 16, I already got some new ways to get the content info but still lack at url, do you know how to item.content['#node'].title.value to the url itself ?

Thank you for always there for me.